# How Do I type in 2 Boxes With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have a text input box, that I want to type in,and as I type, it transfers to another input box on the page.

I set up a JS Fiddle for a sample of what Im looking for. I would like for the text that you type in on the first box, to be transferred to another box on the page or two boxes

here is the jsfiddle

jsfiddle.net/8PrhJ/

so i dont have any javascript in there yet. but can i do this without having a submit button

Comment: For the answer below, you can even set up a class, instead of using ID properties for each box, so that the text you type in any box will show up in the rest of the boxes with the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery it's easy

```
$('#input1').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#input2').val(this.value);
});
```

Plain JS:

```
(function() {
    var input1   = document.getElementById('input1'),
        input2   = document.getElementById('input2'),
        callback = function () {
            input2.value = this.value;
        };

    if (input1.addEventListener) {
        input1.addEventListener('keyup', callback);
    } else {
        input1.attachEvent('onkeyup', callback);
    }
}());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/seancannon/7TL5P/

Comment: Question was not tagged as jQuery, nor was jQuery mentioned by the OP. jQuery is not a solution to all of the world's problems.

Comment: Relax white knight. Hardly worth a downvote, because, as you can see from the above code, just because the OP didn't mention jQuery doesn't mean it's not a better answer than vanilla JS.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, why bind to `keyup` instead of `keypress` or `input`? Using `keyup`, if a user holds a key for a longer amount of time, the values won't duplicate until the key is depressed

Comment: Perhaps, but if I'm going to write something, then I'm going to make sure that that code works properly, for idiots and geniuses alike. And it's not exactly hard to write `keypress` instead of `keyup`. Also, with your jQuery version of this code, you're forcing jQuery to create a new object of `this` and `#input2` each time a key is depressed, which IMHO isn't good.

Comment: Do you have any demo's I could see on jsfiddle

Comment: You mean in addition to the jsfiddle demo link I included below my answer?

Comment: Both of you, I appreciate the JSFiddle demo that you posted. It was very helpful, and I ended up adding onto it for some other code im working on. I didn't use the jQuery, but mainly because I don't know it. I want to finish learning javascript first. +1 to AlienWebGuy, thank you.